Is my proposed algorithm optimal wrt lower bound of the error probability of not identifying the best arm in fixed-budget Best Arm Identification?
The error probability of misidentification in fixed-budget Best Arm Identification has a lower bound of
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{T}{H \log K}\right),
$$
where

$H = \sum_{k \neq k*} \frac{1}{\Delta^2_k}$,
$k*$ is the optimal arm and
$\Delta_k$ is the sub-optimal gap.

[Refer to Alexandra Carpentier and Andrea Locatelli, "Tight (Lower) Bounds for the Fixed Budget Best Arm Identification Bandit Problem", JMLR: Workshop and Conference Proceedings vol 49, pp. 1–15, 2016]
Note that
$$
H \leq \frac{K}{\Delta^2_{min}}
$$
where $\Delta_{min}$ is the minimum of the sub-optimal gaps.
The Sequential Halving algorithm has an upper bound of error probability of
$$
O\left(\log(K)\exp\left(-\frac{T}{H_2 \log K}\right)\right),\quad H_2 < H
$$ So, Sequential halving is the optimal algorithm up to the multiplicative term $\log(K)$.
[Refer to: Zohar Karnin and Tomer Koren and Oren Somekh,"Almost Optimal Exploration in Multi-Armed Bandits",
Proceedings of the 30th International Conference on Ma- chine Learning, Atlanta, Georgia, USA, 2013, JMLR: Workshop and Conference Proceedings vol. 28, pp. 1-9, 2013]
According to my problem, the bound of Sequential Halving is revised to
$$
O\left(\log(K)\exp\left(-\frac{T (\Delta_{min})^2}{K \log K \mu^{*}}\right)\right),
$$
where $\mu^{*}$ is the mean of the optimal arm.
On the other hand, my proposed algorithm gives an upper bound of error probability as
$$
O\left(\log(K)\exp\left(-\frac{T (\Delta_{min})^2}{\log K \mu^{*}}\right)\right),
$$
where $K$ is not in the denominator of the exponent in the error bound term as compared to the Sequential Halving.
My algorithm is improving Sequential Halving, but can we say my proposed algorithm is optimal up to the multiplicative term $\log(K)$?
Your suggestions are highly appreciated.
